# Mysql multivariable linear regression

Tags: mysql, matrix, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to do a multivarible (9 variables) linear regression on data in my mysql 5.0 database (the result value field only has 2 possible values, 1 and 0).

I've done some searching and found I can use:

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> @n := COUNT(score) AS N,
    -> @meanX := AVG(age) AS "X mean",
    -> @sumX := SUM(age) AS "X sum",
    -> @sumXX := SUM(age*age) "X sum of squares",
    -> @meanY := AVG(score) AS "Y mean",
    -> @sumY := SUM(score) AS "Y sum",
    -> @sumYY := SUM(score*score) "Y sum of square",
    -> @sumXY := SUM(age*score) AS "X*Y sum"
```

To get at many of the basic regression variables, but I really don't want to type out doing this for every combination of the 9 variables.  All of the sources I can find about how to do regression on multi variables requires **Matrix operations**.  Can I do Matrix operations with mysql, or are there other ways to do a 9 variable linear regression?

Should I export the data out of mysql first?  Its ~80,000 rows, so it would be alright to move it, just not sure what else I should use.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to store this data in MySQL but you could process the data from a language that has access to the database. Pseudocode:

```
variables = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' ];

for X in $variables do
    for Y in $variables do
        query = 'SELECT
            @'+$X+$Y+' := COUNT(score) AS '+$X+$Y+',
            @mean'+$X+' := AVG(age) AS "X mean",
            @sum'+$X+' := SUM(age) AS "X sum",
            @sum'+$X+$X+' := SUM(age*age) "X sum of squares",
            @mean'+$Y+' := AVG(score) AS "Y mean",
            @sum'+$Y+' := SUM(score) AS "Y sum",
            @sum'+$Y+$Y+' := SUM(score*score) "Y sum of square",
            @sum'+$X+$Y+' := SUM(age*score) AS "X*Y sum"';
        db_execute(query);
    done
done
```

but why do not store the results in a table? More appropriate for a database.

```
for X in $variables do
    for Y in $variables do
        query = 'INSERT INTO regression SELECT FROM measurements
            "'+$X+'" AS X
            "'+$Y+'" AS Y
            score AS valX
            age AS valY
            COUNT(score) AS N,
            AVG(age) AS meanX,
            SUM(age) AS sumX,
            SUM(age*age) squareX,
            AVG(score) AS meanY,
            SUM(score) AS sumY,
            SUM(score*score) squareY,
            SUM(age*score) AS sumXY';
        db_execute(query);
    done
done
```

Put separate index on both X and the Y columns.

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend moving the data out of MySQL and into R. With 1/0 response data a logistic regression is much more appropriate and it is not the simple sum of squares you are implementing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

This seems to do a good job of showing how to solve the logistic

http://www.omidrouhani.com/research/logisticregression/html/logisticregression.htm#_Toc147483467